# need to create using SCP allowing users to create any resource only if they create tags in the process

Tags: aws-scp

i want to create an scp policy that restricts users for creating any resource with out tags

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect": "Deny",
"Action": "*",
"Resource": "*",
"Condition": {
"StringNotEquals": {
"aws:RequestTag/cost_center": "Test",
"aws:RequestTag/squad": "Test"
}
}
}